# Ajax request with setInterval that blinks

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this piece of code which aim is to get the content of a file and put it    in a div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   setInterval("loadXMLDoc()",2000);
   function loadXMLDoc(){
        var xmlhttp;
       // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
           document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
       }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_doc.txt",true);
      xmlhttp.send();
   }
 </script>
```

But in Chrome, Opera and Safari the text in the div blinks every 2 seconds. In Firefox this don't happen. What can I do to avoid the blinking? the code is running in a local machine with Appache. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try adding an if statement to your onreadystatechange handler to check that the request is finished as there are other ready states it could be. You should also check the status is ok (200) as opposed to page not found (404)

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
```

The setInterval function continues to call the function at the specified interval until the clearInterval method is called.
The setTimeout function which will only call the function once, which will stop the page refreshing.

Comment: My goal is verifying the latest content in the file. Because the content can be modified I need a periodic verification.